# NSOperation subclass release make Instruments crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, instruments, nsoperation

I ran instruments on my Mac OS X application in `Xcode 4.5`. I have two `NSOperation` dependent subclasses that I forgot to release after adding them in a process queue. So I released them just after adding them in the queue. The application works great. I profiles it on Instruments but it crashes.

```
processQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSUInteger max = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"jobsKey"];
processQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = max;
GeocacheDownloadOperation * downloadOp = [[GeocacheDownloadOperation alloc]  initWithGeocache:cache InPath:directoryPath withDelegate:self];        
GeocacheJPGConversionOperation * conversionOp = [[GeocacheJPGConversionOperation alloc] initWithCache:cache WithPath:directoryPath WithDelegate:self];

[conversionOp addDependency:downloadOp];     
[processQueue addOperation:downloadOp];
[processQueue addOperation:conversionOp];

[downloadOp release];
[conversionOp release]; //This line makes Instruments crash
```

`Instruments` crash when I want to release the last operation (see on code) but the application seems to work great.

Did someone have a suggestion ? Is it an Instruments bug or did I code something wrong ?

Comment: How do you know it is your app that is making instruments crash?

Comment: When I comment the last line in the code posted, Instruments works well. It crashes because an segmentation error.

Comment: It's probably something inside the conversionOp class, do you override dealloc?

Comment: I override dealloc and just release one string object. But it should not change anything. When you add one operation in a process queue, it is retained. And the app only crash in Intruments.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that conversionOp releases every dependency (so downloadOp in this case) when deallocated. So you call [conversionOp release] after both operations are finished (and this depends on how the threads are scheduled), so you over-release downloadOp.

Comment: I tried be deleting first the `[downloadOp release]` only. The app still crashs within Instruments. Then I delete the second release, Instruments works but I have leaks with `GeocacheDownloadOperation` and `GeocacheJPGConversionOperation` ...

Comment: Can you show also GeocacheDownloadOperation and GeocacheJPGConversionOperation classes?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not allowed to publish it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the error but I can't explain why it was working alone and not in Instruments. I used a released variable in the `NSOperation` subclasses, that I released the second times in the `dealloc` function of the NSOperation subclasses. Now, I don't override `[super dealloc]` anymore in the `NSOperation`subclasses and it works.